# Подгрузка контроллеров

Tags: mvc, php

Пишу систему используя паттерн MVC. Встал вопрос о том как подгружать контроллеры.
Есть вариант использовать autoload, но тогда придется ограничится одним каталогом, однако мне хотелось разделить логически некоторые модули. Или можно создать свой загрузчик и явно его вызывать и тогда можно будет из любых каталогов подгружать. Так как же правильнее?
Отказаться от автозагрузки и явно подгружать или отказаться от структуры подкаталогов и использовать autoload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется **автолоад** предпочтительнее - можно "забыть" про некоторые вещи (в хорошем смысле), все будет само выполнятся. Соответственно ошибок меньше.

А структура каталогов - это уже зависит от организации ума. :) Кому-то (мне) важнее автоматизация, нежели древовидная структура, кому-то - визуальный порядок и структура.

P.S. Какой хоть фреймворк юзаете?

Comment: никакой)

Comment: Я полагаю что тут все же лучше пользоваться явной подгрузкой.

Comment: Я увидел гениальное решение сочетающее 2 метода, но autoload используется несколько по другому. autoload для подгрузки корневых классов и класс bootstrap для подгрузки контроллеров

Answer (score 0):

Возьмите Кохану и не мучайтесь!
Имхо, вы изобретаете свой велосипед с квадратными колёсами и штырём вместо седла!

Comment: еще скажите "возьми joomla и не парься"

Comment: просто жесть :)

Comment: @Сергей Не, лучше - да бросьте Вы этот PHP и вообще веб дизайн и не парьтесь... Пользуйтесь C++ и STL

Answer (score 0):

Касаемо ограничиться одним каталогом, можно сделать примерно так:

```
<?php
/*
 * bootstrap.php
 */
ini_set( "include_path",
        implode( PATH_SEPARATOR,
                array(
                        ini_get("include_path"),        # default include path
                        dirname( __FILE__ ),
                )
        )
);
function __autoload( $name ) {
        if( preg_match_all( "/([A-Z]*[^A-Z]*)/", $name, $match, PREG_SET_ORDER ) ) {
                $words = array();
                foreach ( $match as $re ) {
                        if( !empty( $re[1] ) ) {
                                $words[] = strtolower( $re[1] );
                        }
                }
                $name = implode( DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $words ) . '.php';
        }
        require_once( $name );
}
```

Собственно все файлы будут хранится в дереве каталогов где bootstrap.php находится в корне. Или если отказаться от первого ini_set, то там где указанно в include_path.

Как это использовать:

```
<?php
/*
 * index.php
 */

require_once("{root}/bootstrap.php");

class MyController extends BaseController {
    # ...
    function __construct() {
        $this->dbh = new ServerDAO(...)
    }
}
```

Соответственно класс BaseController будет взят из файла base/controller.php а для класса ServerDAO будет подгружен файл server/dao.php

Дерево каталогов для данного примера:

- {root}/
- {root}/bootstrap.php
- {root}/base/controller.php
- {root}/server/dao.php